Python FastApi - Import error: No module named 'routers'
i am trying to build FastAPi with my custom api provider.
Following the fastapi guide by documentation.
When i run this command : fastapi run
It gives an error: ERROR    Import error: No module named 'routers'
I have double checked init.py file is exist under routers folder and project's main folder.
Here is the main.py:
import sys
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

#from core.config import settings
import sys
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
sys.path.append('/routers/chat_order_router')  # Append the directory 
from  routers.chat_order_router import order_router

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(order_router)

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

chat_order_router.py :
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List

from dependencies import get_db
from schemas.chat_schema import ChatCreateSchema, ChatResponseSchema
from models.chat import Chat
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from services.zus_backend_service import ZusBackendService  # Ensure this is correctly imported

import pytest
from httpx import Response

order_router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/chats_order",
    tags=["chats_order"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)

load_dotenv()

# Dependency
def get_zus_service():
    base_uri = os.getenv('ZUS_BE_URL')  # Default value if not set
    client_name = os.getenv('ZUS_BE_NAME')
    client_secret = os.getenv('ZUS_BE_SECRET')

    if not base_uri or not client_name or not client_secret:
        raise Exception("Critical environment variables are missing for ZusBackendService")

    return ZusBackendService(base_uri, client_name, client_secret)

@order_router.get("/order-details/{order_id}")
async def order_details(order_id: str, zus_service: ZusBackendService = Depends(get_zus_service)):
    order_details = zus_service.get_order_details({"order_no": order_id})
    if not order_details:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Order not found")
    return order_details

@order_router.post("/", response_model=ChatResponseSchema, status_code=201)
def create_chat_orders(chat: ChatCreateSchema, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    new_chat = Chat(**chat.dict())
    db.add(new_chat)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_chat)
    return new_chat

@order_router.get("/", response_model=List[ChatResponseSchema])
def read_chats_orders(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    chats = db.query(Chat).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
    return chats

@order_router.get("/{chat_id}", response_model=ChatResponseSchema)
def read_chats_orders(chat_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    chat = db.query(Chat).filter(Chat.id == chat_id).first()
    if chat is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Chat not found")
    return chat

@order_router.get("/check_order/{order_id}", status_code=200)
def check_order(order_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    """API endpoint to check if an order exists."""
    # Check directly if an order exists by querying the Chat table.
    order_exists = db.query(Chat).filter(Chat.order_id == order_id).first() is not None
    if order_exists:
        return {"message": "Order exists."}
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Order not found")

And project's file structure:


For the sake of your own sanity, do not toy with sys.path! There is no need for that sys.path.append('/routers/chat_order_router') (especially since it's expecting there to be a directory called routers in your filesystem root, with a subdirectory, but even beyond the typos, don't!)
from routers.chat_order_router import order_router would otherwise work fine, but you've made zus-chatbot-middleware-v2 also a package (as we can tell from __init__.py) and main is being imported from that package.
IOW, the directory containing zus-chatbot-middleware-v2 is on sys.path, and you should import relatively from its subpackages:
from .routers.chat_order_router import router

or
from zus-chatbot-middleware-v2.routers.chat_order_router import router

which won't work because dashes aren't allowed in Python identifiers.
My personal refactoring recommendation here would be to wrap everything code-related (so not README.md, .gitignore, etc) in a package, let's say zus, in your project directory (zus-chatbot-middleware-v2) and point your server to that (e.g. zus.main). Then you can use from zus.routers import ... or from zus.models import ... and all package paths are unambiguous.

thanks it works like this .routers.chat_order_router import router
